# How to get the status code if i am using a generated stub class by axis2 WSDL2Java tool.?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, stub

I need to check the status code of the webservice for a specific checking in my code. but im using a stub generated by axis2 wsdl2java tool. and i dont know how to get it. can any one tell me how to get the status code from the stub class?

```
String sResult = "";
Service1Stub serviceStub = new Service1Stub();
VLDTACCT requestVLDTACCT = new VLDTACCT();
requestVLDTACCT.setAcct("");
VLDTACCTResponse responseVLDTACCT = serviceStub.vLDTACCT(requestVLDTACCT);
System.out.println(responseVLDTACCT.getVLDTACCTResult());
if(http_response_code == 200) {
    sResponse = "Passed";
} else {
    sResponse = "Down";
}
```

I have to get the response code or status code. can you help me please?

Comment: Can you provide some pseudo code to clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ Philippe A.String sResult = ""; Service1Stub serviceStub = new Service1Stub(); VLDTACCT requestVLDTACCT = new VLDTACCT(); requestVLDTACCT.setAcct(""); VLDTACCTResponse responseVLDTACCT = serviceStub.vLDTACCT(requestVLDTACCT); System.out.println(responseVLDTACCT.getVLDTACCTResult()); if(http_response_code == 200){ sResponse = "Passed";}else{sResponse = "Down"}


I have to get the response code or status code. can you help me please?